# Carrying out same function on different F# record types with identical labels

Tags: f#, record

Suppose I have following record types and their lists:

```
type Employee = {            
    id:int
    name:string
}

type Project = {            
    id:int
    name:string
}

let el = [{Employee.id = 1; name = "E1"};{Employee.id = 2; name = "E2"};{Employee.id = 3; name = "E3"};]
let pl = [{Project.id = 5; name = "P1"};{Project.id = 6; name = "P2"};{Project.id = 7; name = "P3"};]
```

I want to apply the same function(as defined below) to both type lists but the type inferred is Project.

```
let CreateFormattedStringList l =
    l |> List.map(fun x -> (x.id |> string) + "@" + x.name)
//function signature:
//val CreateFormattedStringList : l:Project list -> string list

let res_1 =  el |> CreateFormattedStringList //error
let res_2 =  pl |> CreateFormattedStringList //ok
```

I found this helpful [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24984247/compiler-cant-tell-which-record-type-with-duplicate-fields-should-be-the-functi) which shows a simple value returned. So, the following works for both types of lists in my case:

```
let inline CreateFormattedStringList (l: ^T list) =
    (^T: (member id:int) (l.Head))
```

Now I am unable to wrap my head around how to apply the more elaborate function in same way. Something like:

```
let inline CreateFormattedStringList (l: ^T list) =
    l |> List.map(fun (^T: (member id:int) (x)) -> (x.id |> string) + "@" + x.name)
//error
```

I am trying to find examples but aren't able to. How can I use inline to be able to apply the same function to both types? Also, how to add constraint for 'name' and 'id' both?

Comment: checkout this answer and this blogpost https://robkuz.github.io/HKTS-in-fsharp-part-III-Concept-Emulation/

Comment: `l |> List.map(fun x -> ((^T: (member id:int) x) |> string) + "@" + (^T: (member name:string) x))`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, I think it's simpler to write a function that works on a single item instead of a list and then use it with other higher order functions like `List.map` if necessary.

The syntax for this is confusing, but what you had working so far was actually a function that contains an expression that uses the `id` member, while also asserting that the input type has an `id` member. So you need to add another expression for `name`. It's easier to tell what's going on if you bind those to names:

```
let inline formatIdName (x: ^T) =
    let id = (^T: (member id:int) x)
    let name = (^T: (member name:string) x)
    sprintf "%i - %s" id name

formatIdName {Employee.id = 1; name = "E1"} // "1 - E1"
formatIdName {Project.id = 5;  name = "P1"} // "5 - P1"
```